# condition error in loc in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following date frame.

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({'month':[2,3,7,8],'day':[29,24,20,29]})
>>> mydf
   day  month
0   29      2
1   24      3
2   20      7
3   29      8

>>> leapdf =  mydf.loc[(mydf['month'] == 2) & (mydf['day'] == 29) ]
>>> leapdf
   day  month
0   29      2

>>> otherdf =  mydf.loc[(mydf['month'] != 2) & (mydf['day'] != 29) ]
>>> otherdf
   day  month
1   24      3
2   20      7
```

Above otherdf I am expecting day 29 and month 8 to be included. But not included. Can any one guide me what is the error.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect day 29 to be included when you explicitly denied it? `(mydf['day'] != 29)`.  Your filter removes all months of Feb and all days (regardless of month) equal to day 29.

Comment: thanks got the mistake

Answer (score 1):

You need `|` for `or`:

```
otherdf =  mydf.loc[(mydf['month'] != 2) | (mydf['day'] != 29) ]
```

What is same as:

```
otherdf =  mydf.loc[~((mydf['month'] == 2) & (mydf['day'] == 29)) ]
print (otherdf)
   day  month
1   24      3
2   20      7
3   29      8
```